# Bluemix added a PENDING state to user profiles

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to print out this new state from the getUsers REST API. What field in the SoftLayer_User_Customer contains the new profile state PENDING?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to get that value from the customers records, it is only for internal purposes, by the way, that status means that the customer is pending for email confirmation. My apologies for the inconveniences

Comment: Here is the problem. I should probably ask Buemix.  If I try to give the user with pending state access to a service, I get a message that the user isn't in the proper state.  If I could check the state of the user then I wouldn't try to give the user access to any service.  I am amazed I can't get access to the user state.

Comment: My apologies, but unfortunately there is no way to check that from SoftLayer's API, because it is from BlueMix side

Comment: Thank you! Will pester Bluemix.

Comment: Just for clarity, SoftLayer and Bluemix are one entity. SoftLayer is called Bluemix Infrastructure (IaaS). There are PaaS APIs (Bluemix services) and IaaS APIs (Bluemix Infrastructure).